# Worker Queue published directly to a Q (not an Exchange)

Tags: rabbitmq

Example for worker queue here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

In the worker-queue scenario, why are messages published to a Queue, and not an Exchange?

```
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                     routingKey: "task_queue",
                     basicProperties: properties,
                     body: body);
```

Comment: any updates on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you give routing key to "" - nameless exchange (so you actually are always publishing to an exchange), that routing key "is" actually the queue name.
Here is a quote from [tutorial 3](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html):

> **Nameless exchange**
>
> In previous parts of the tutorial we knew nothing about exchanges, but
>   still were able to send messages to queues. That was possible because
>   we were using a default exchange, which we **identify by the empty**
>   string ("").
>
> Recall how we published a message before:
>
> ```
> var message = GetMessage(args); var body =
> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message); channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
>                      routingKey: "hello",
>                      basicProperties: null,
>                      body: body);
> ```
>
> The first parameter is the the name of the exchange. The empty string denotes the **default or nameless exchange**: messages are routed to the queue with the name specified by
>   routingKey, if it exists.